# Can't `lvconvert` when root is readonly

Tags: lvm, snapshot, read-only, thin-provisioning

My root is mounted readonly (on purpose). I have a separate, read-write vg where I want to `lvconvert --merge` a thin snapshot. I'm getting `Cannot archive volume group metadata for $VG to read-only filesystem`. The manpage was unhelpful. Is there some flag I can pass to disable this "archive" functionality or to control where the archive is written?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this w/o create a backup and change the file in `/etc/lvm/archive` So remount temporary the `root` filesystem as r/w, exec the operation and remount it as r/o.